# Core Data NSFetchrequest integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following scenario. I have an app that handles data by using Core Data. I have an entity called "Brothers" which has 3 attributes: Name, Status, Age.

lets say that I have 1 record on my database that has:

```
-Name   ==> Joe (String)
-Status ==> Married (String)
-Age    ==> 28 (Integer)
```

I have an UIlabel a UItextfield and a Button. I want to be able to type the name (in this case Joe) on the UItextfield press the button and display the age (in this case 28) in the UILabel. I would also like to store the age value into a variable type integer so I can make some calculations with it later on.

below the code that I have inside the button.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Brothers" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age %d", [self.age.text integerValue]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *integer = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

self.displayLabel.text = integer;
```

**Update #1**

I updated the code that i have inside the button and now i am able to search by the name and display the age. I'm still looking into storing the age as an integer into a variable so i can use it later on.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Brothers" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname like %@", self.firstnameTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *integer = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if(integer.count <= 0){
    self.displayLabel.text = @"No records found";

}

else {

    NSString *age;

    for (NSManagedObject *object in integer) {

        age = [object valueForKey:@"age"];

    }
    self.displayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"age: %@",age];
                              }

}
```

Comment: If you want to search for the *name*, why do you use a predicate with *age*? - Assigning an NSArray to a text field? - Reading the "Core Data Programming Guide" and "Predicate Programming Guide" might be helpful.

Comment: my mistake. I just fixed it and will edit the code in the post. i was able to display the age on my UILabel when i search by the name. I am still trying to store the age value as an integer into a variable.

Comment: If "age" is defined as an Core Data "Integer" attribute, then the value is stored as NSNumber. So `NSNumber *age = [object valueForKey:@"age"]`, which you can convert to a plain integer: `int i = [age intValue]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A predicate is an expression. If the expression evaluates to true then the predicate is satisfied. So if you were searching by age you'd use e.g.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age = %d", [self.age.text integerValue]]
```

Or by name:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", someNameOrOther]
```

Or by both:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@) and (age = %d)", someNameOrOther, [self.age.text integerValue]]
```

A fetch request gets the actual `NSManagedObject`s. So you'd get back an array of `Brother`s. Therefore you probably want something more like this to output a name:

```
if([array count])
    self.displayLabel.text = [array[0] name];
```

Or for an age:

```
...
    self.displayLabel.text = [[array[0] age] stringValue];
```

Or whatever other property you're outputting.

Comment: The OP said to search by name so the predicate should filter by name and not by age.

Comment: @JuanCatalan you're right. By starting with his code I've completely ignored his description. I'm a very blind person sometimes. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your predicate is wrong, the proper format would be this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age.integerValue == %d", [self.age.text integerValue]];
```

Comment: The "integerValue" is actually not needed, `@"age = %d", someInt"` should work. But OP said that he wants to search for the *name* and display the *age*.